# How can I customize order of navigation buttons on Android 5 (or 6 if not possible)?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 5.0-lollipop, navigation-bar

I saw a lot of tutorials where people talk about software called "Customize Navigation Bar" that requires at least Android 7.0. I wonder if it's possible to do it on Sony Xperia M5 that has only Android 5 and 6 available.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have a spare Android device 5.1.1. I remember using an app called keymapper to arrange/customize my navigation bar. You could give it a try. This app is a part of opensource project.

Here's the link to Key Mapper

https://f-droid.org/en/packages/io.github.sds100.keymapper/

***N.B. Although you can try downloading from the link directly, I wouldn't advice that since Android versions could be mismatched. I suggest you download fdroid and then try downloading from there. Hopefully this helps.***